# iOS Use RxSwift to track when the async network call has completed

Tags: ios, rx-swift

I'm working to integrate RxSwift into my project

I have written an async network request which have result is pass on a callback closure.

Here is my network function

```
func discoverMovies(for url: String, withPage page: Int, success: @escaping(Bool)->()) {

        let requestUrl = "\(url)&page=\(page)"

        requestGETURL(requestUrl, success: { (json) in

            self.createOrUpdateMoviesList(from: json)   
            success(true)

        }) { (error) in
            print("Could not download due to \(error)")
            success(false)
        }
    }
```

My question is how can we register an `Observable` that observe the result of the network call (either success is true or false) so that we can write additional handle base on the result (additional code will only be execute after the network has completed).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would wrap your functions into Rx-functions:

```
func discoverMovies(for url: String, withPage page: Int) -> Observable<MoviesList>{
    Observable.create{ observer in 

        let requestUrl = "\(url)&page=\(page)"

        self.requestGETURL(requestUrl, success: { (json) in

            // your createOrUpdateMoviesList(from:) function returns a MoviesList
            let moviesList = self.createOrUpdateMoviesList(from: json)   
            observer.onNext(moviesList)
            observer.onCompleted()

        }) { (error) in
            print("Could not download due to \(error)")
            observer.onError(error)
        }

        return Disposables.create()
    }
}

func otherFunction(withMovies list: MoviesList) -> Observable<Something> {
    // blah blah blah...
}
```

Now you can chain your Rx-functions with `flatMap` operator:

```
discoverMovies(for url: "the url", withPage page: 1)
    .flatMap{ list in 
        otherFunction(withMovies: list)  
    }
    .subscribe(onNext:{ something in
        // ...
    },
     onError: { error in
        // manage errors
    })
```

You can be sure that your `otherFunction()` only will be called if `discoverMovies()` has a success result.

Comment: Thanks a lot quite get the Ideal. The key here is the flatmap function. I ll try to implement it